# Login screen doesn't remember my choice of desktop environment

Tags: 11.10, login, gnome, lightdm

I have installed GNOME Shell, logged into it, but on boot the computer logs in to an Ubuntu session. I have automatic login enabled.

How can I fix this? How can I make Ubuntu remember my choice of desktop environment?

Answer (score 6):

Edit lightdm.conf with gedit and change the `user-session=ubuntu` to `user-session=gnome`

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Edit gnome.desktop with gedit and change `Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu` to `Exec=gnome-session --session=gnome`

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop
```

After this you will login directly to you gnome desktop ;)

Comment: Already edited the lightdm.conf and now I login directly to the gnome desktop, but I'm still waiting for a solution that better fixes this.

Comment: If you want to report it as a bug please [feel free to do so](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), unfortunately there is nothing I can do about that. ;)

Comment: This works, thanks. Only problem is that normal Ubuntu updates will overwrite these config files (at least they appear to have done so for me). We should probably file a bug to get it resolved in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you use either of the two answers:

*edit lightdm.conf & gnome.desktop*

-or-

```
apt-get remove unity
```

be sure to edit `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop` and change

```
Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
```

to

```
Exec=gnome-session --session=gnome
```

From terminal...

```
sudo nano /usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked: Reinstall and **make sure password is required to sign in is checked**.  This allows the gnome to install and work properly.

Answer (score -2):

I wish this worked.  I had to remove Unity-desktop to get it to allow me into gnome-shell

```
sudo apt-get remove unity
```

Comment: This is to much, way to much radical. It's much more simple to edit a 4 - 5 line file than remove unity. Plus I want to have them both.

Comment: I was going to downvote this, but I think the point is already made that there are much better ways to solve this problem.