# How to set up Gnome-Shell as the default DE?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login screen doesn't remember my choice of desktop enviroment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65753/login-screen-doesnt-remember-my-choice-of-desktop-enviroment)

Pretty all in the question. I can choose "Gnome" at login, but I set "automatic login" and always come to Unity...and I do prefer Gnome Shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shell as your default DE then just use this command--

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-shell
```

and to revert back just change gnome-shell to ubuntu

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu
```

similarly you can set any DE your default just put the name of it at the back.

Comment: Recommend moving this answer to the possible duplicate here http://askubuntu.com/questions/65753/login-screen-doesnt-remember-my-choice-of-desktop-enviroment